# How do you output the type of $_FILE error with PHP?

Tags: php, file

I keep on getting this error when uploading an image with PHP. I know how to count the number of errors:

```
$file = $_FILES["file"];
echo $file_error = $file["error"];
```

How do I echo the type of error with PHP?

Comment: You RTMs http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php - http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you! I thought $file_error referred to the # of errors, not the type of error. Do you know how I can change the max file size in php.ini?

Comment: you're welcome. you've an answer below. they can answer you I'm sure ;-) and nothing that can't be Google'd ;-)

Comment: `how I can change the max file size in php.ini` - open php.ini and change!

Comment: @Fred-ii- You deserve the "accepted answer." I fixed the problem...

Comment: @ProgrammingTree done ;-) glad to hear it, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read through the manuals, it's all in there.

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Plus, for your other question in comments:

> *"Do you know how I can change the max file size in php.ini?"*

Consult the following on Stack:

- [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

and in the manual on Description of core php.ini directives of course.

- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php